# When using the accept_nested_attributes_for method, what actually happens when I tell my controller to build the nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

What I'm trying to do is update a created item's attributes after it is created through the controller, like so:

```
 def create
    @check_out = CheckOut.new(params[:check_out]) 
    @check_out.request_id = @request.id
    @check_out.status = 'complete'
    @check_out.date_taken = Time.now
    etc.....

    respond_to do |format|
      if @check_out.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@check_out, :notice => 'Check out was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @check_out, :status => :created, :location => @check_out }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @check_out.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue is that the item created, is created via a nested attribute. I've come to realize, through painful trial and error, that when nested items are created, it is not through their controller, but some other way. I need to figure out how this is done, so I can attempt to come up with a solution.

Comment: Modifying objects in the controller is a BAD practice.

Answer (score 0):

The good place to start http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Trust me, I know, generally, how nested models work. I need specifics, and how to update a created nested models attributes via the controller.